# How to edit DataGridView on button Click

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView in which I am binding some records. I have a button Edit on my form. I want to Edit all the rows and column of the datagridview when I click on button Edit, so that user can change the data as per there need, and the data which is changed it should show in different color, so that user can recognizes that this data got changed.

till binding of grid I have done, how to edit and assign the color into changed cell I am unable to find solution.

Please something help me, with some exp. code. or some sugg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `EditMode` and ReadOnly

You set `EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`.

You set  `ReadOnly` to true for the cell, row, column, and control.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.80)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a property for that `Enable Editing`.

And after that you can apply formatting with the help of `DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event`

[image: Enable Editing]

Comment: I have done that but its not working, I am unable to edit the grid on button Edit Click

Comment: you can't edit all cell at once..but you will see and edit link on each row..by which you can edit each cell...